# NInject, nHibernate, and auditing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, ninject, auditing

I am working on an inherited application which makes use of NInject and nHibernate as part of an ASP.NET MVC (C#) application. Currently, I'm looking at a problem with the auditing of modifications. Each entity has ChangedOn/ChangedBy and CreatedOn/CreatedBy fields, which are mapped to database columns. However, these either get filled with the wrong username or no username at all. I think this is because it has been configured in the wrong way, but I don't know enough about nHibernate and NInject to solve the issue, so I hope someone can help. Below some code snippets to hopefully provide sufficient insight in the application.

**Creating the session factory and session:**

```
public class NHibernateModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider(new SessionFactoryProvider()).InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider()).InRequestScope();
        Bind<INHibernateUnitOfWork>().To<NHibernateUnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<User>().ToProvider(new UserProvider()).InRequestScope();
        Bind<IStamper>().ToProvider(new StamperProvider()).InRequestScope();
    }
}

public class SessionProvider : Provider<ISession>
{
    protected override ISession CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        // Create session
        var sessionFactory = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>();            
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();            
        session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;

        return session;
    }
}

public class SessionFactoryProvider : Provider<ISessionFactory>
{
    protected override ISessionFactory CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionString"].ToString();
        var stamper = context.Kernel.Get<IStamper>();

        return NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory(connectionString, stamper);
    }
}

public class StamperProvider : Provider<IStamper>
{
    protected override IStamper CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = user == null ? null : user.Identity;
        string name = identity == null ? "Unknown" : identity.Name;

        return new Stamper(name);
    }
}

public class UserProvider : Provider<User>
{
    protected override UserCreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var userRepos = context.Kernel.Get<IUserRepository>();

        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = user == null ? null : user.Identity;
        string name = identity == null ? "" : identity.Name;

        var user = userRepos.GetByName(name);
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Configuring the session factory:**

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(string connectionString, IStamper stamper)
    {
        // Info: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration
        return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .Mappings(m => 
                    {
                        m.FluentMappings
                            .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "Id"))
                            .AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateHelper>();

                        m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateHelper>();
                    })
                // Register 
                .ExposeConfiguration(c => {
                    c.EventListeners.PreInsertEventListeners = 
                        new IPreInsertEventListener[] { new EventListener(stamper) };
                    c.EventListeners.PreUpdateEventListeners =
                        new IPreUpdateEventListener[] { new EventListener(stamper) };
                })
                .BuildSessionFactory();
     }
```

**Snippet from the eventlistener:**

```
public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent e)
{
    _stamper.Insert(e.Entity as IStampedEntity, e.State, e.Persister);
    return false;
}
```

As you can see the session factory is in a singleton scope. Therefore the eventlistener and stamper also get instantiated in this scope (I think). And this means that when the user is not yet logged in, the username in the stamper is set to an empty string or "Unknown".
I tried to compensate for this problem, by modifying the Stamper. It checks if the username is null or empty. If this is true, it tries to find the active user, and fill the username-property with that user's name:

```
    private string GetUserName()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_userName))
        {
            var user = ServiceLocator.Resolve<User>();

            if (user != null)
            {
                _userName = user.UserName;
            }
        }

        return _userName;
    }
```

But this results in a completely different user's name, which is also logged in to the application, being logged in the database. My guess this is because it resolves the wrong active user, being the last user logged in, instead of the user that started the transaction.

Comment: What does the code in UserProvider and StamperProvider look like?  SessionFactory is configured as singleton because creating a SessionFactory is relatively expensive and you really only need one.  The ISession is the NHibernate session that actually talks to the database and it's being created for each RequestScope which means you get a new one for each web request.  I'm wondering how your UserProvider gets the current user and what the StamperProvider does to attach it to the entity.

Comment: Nathan, if you scroll a bit down in the code block with session and session factory, you can see those two providers as well. I figured that would be important, but the code-block is a bit large so SO's stylesheet hides the overflow with a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaronaught, you're analysis describes exactly what I suspected. However, I found there is a fourth solution which is easier and more straightforward IMHO.
I modified the sessionprovider, such that the call to `OpenSession` takes an instance of IInterceptor as argument. As it turns out, the event listeners aren't actually supposed to be used for auditing ([a bit of a rant, but other than that he is right, according to Fabio as well](http://www.scottfindlater.co.uk/blog/nhibernate-the-bizarre-arrogance)).

The `AuditInterceptor` implements `OnFlushDirty` (for auditing existing entities) and `OnSave` (for auditing newly created entities). The `SessionProvider` looks as below:

```
public class SessionProvider : Provider<ISession>
{
    protected override ISession CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        // Create session
        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity = user == null ? null : user.Identity;
        string name = identity == null ? "" : identity.Name;

        var sessionFactory = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>();
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(new AuditInterceptor(name));            
        session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;

        return session;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very poor practice. Dependencies should not be aware of the existence of interceptors, or any other DI/AOP plumbing. IF you want to take this approach, use the Ninject.Extensions.Interception library (preferably the Castle implementation) and add an interceptor to the `ISession` binding, which presumably is where the interceptor is actually getting attached.

Answer (score 4):

The offending parts are here:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>().
    .ToProvider(new SessionFactoryProvider())
    .InSingletonScope();

Bind<IStamper>()
    .ToProvider(new StamperProvider())
    .InRequestScope();
```

And later on:

```
public class SessionFactoryProvider : Provider<ISessionFactory>
{
    protected override ISessionFactory CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        // Unimportant lines omitted
        var stamper = context.Kernel.Get<IStamper>();
        return NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory(connectionString, stamper);
    }
}

public class StamperProvider : Provider<IStamper>
{
    protected override IStamper CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        // Unimportant lines omitted
        string name = /* whatever */
        return new Stamper(name);
    }
}
```

Let's analyze what's going on with the code:

- The `ISessionFactory` is bound as single-instance. There will only ever be one throughout the lifetime of the process. This is fairly typical.
- The `ISessionFactory` is initialized with `SessionFactoryProvider` which immediately goes out to get an instance of `IStamper`, and passes this as a **constant** argument to initialize the session factory.
- The `IStamper` in turn is initialized by the `StamperProvider` which initializes a `Stamper` class with a **constant** `name` set to the **current** user principal/identity.

The net result of this is that **as long as the process is alive, every single "stamp" will be assigned the name of whichever user was first to log in.** This might even be the *anonymous* user, which explains why you're seeing so many blank entries.

Whoever wrote this only got half the equation right. The `IStamper` is bound to the request scope, but it's being *supplied* to a *singleton*, which means that only one `IStamper` will ever be created. You're lucky that the `Stamper` doesn't hold any resources or have any finalizers, otherwise you'd probably end up with a lot of `ObjectDisposedException` and other weird errors.

There are three possible solutions to this:

1. (Recommended) - Rewrite the `Stamper` class to look up the current user on **each call**, instead of being initialized with static user info. Afterward, the `Stamper` class would no longer take any constructor arguments. You can the bind the `IStamper` `InSingletonScope` instead of `InRequestScope`.
2. Create an abstract `IStamperFactory` with a `GetStamper` method, and a concrete `StamperFactory` which implements it by wrapping the `IKernel` instance. Bind these together `InSingletonScope`. Have your concrete factory `return kernel.Get<IStamper>()`. Modify the session factory to accept and hold an `IStamperFactory` *instead of* an `IStamper`. *Each time it needs to stamp*, use the factory to get a new `IStamper` instance.
3. Change the `ISessionFactory` to be `InRequestScope`. **Not recommended** because it will hurt performance and potentially mess up ID generators if you don't use DB-generated identities, but it *will* solve your auditing problem.

Comment: Could you help me in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571742/using-nhibernate-interceptor-together-with-ninject-to-retrieve-the-logged-in-use