# Using NHibernate interceptor together with Ninject to retrieve the logged in user

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ninject, asp.net-mvc-5

I was reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090636/ninject-nhibernate-and-auditing-in-asp-net-mvc) and found it quite interesting (thanks @Aaronaught). Was what came closest to solve my problem.

The only detail is that in my case I would use the NHibernate interceptor, but an exception is thrown `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll`

### Code

Session factory:

```
public class SessionFactoryBuilder : IProvider
{
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly Configuration _configuration;

    public SessionFactoryBuilder(AuditInterceptor auditInterceptor)
    {
        _configuration = Fluently.Configure(new Configuration().Configure())
                .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<IEntidade>(new AutomappingConfiguration())))
                .ExposeConfiguration(SetupDatabase)
                .BuildConfiguration();

        _configuration.SetInterceptor(auditInterceptor);

        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void SetupDatabase(Configuration config)
    {
        var schema = new SchemaExport(config);
        //schema.Execute(true, true, false);
    }

    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        return _sessionFactory;
    }

    public Type Type
    {
        get { return typeof(ISessionFactory); }
    }
}
```

I have a module that sets up my repositories and ORM (NHibernate)

```
public class RepositoriosModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<AuditInterceptor>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

        // NHibernate 
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider<SessionFactoryBuilder>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(CreateSession).InRequestScope();
        Bind<NHUnitOfWork>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

        //Model Repositories
        Bind<IRepositorio<Usuario>, IUsuariosRepositorio>().To<UsuariosRepositorio>().InRequestScope();
    }

    private ISession CreateSession(IContext context)
    {
        return context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Interceptor to update auditable properties (`CriadoEm` (create at), `CriadoPor` (create by), `AtualizadoEm` and `AtualizadoPor`)

```
public class AuditInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private readonly IUsuario _usuarioLogado;
    public AuditInterceptor(IUsuario usuarioLogado)
    {
        _usuarioLogado = usuarioLogado;
    }

    public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, NHibernate.Type.IType[] types)
    {
        var auditableObject = entity as IAuditavel;
        if (auditableObject != null)
        {
            currentState[Array.IndexOf(propertyNames, "AtualizadoEm")] = DateTime.Now;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, NHibernate.Type.IType[] types)
    {
        var auditableObject = entity as IAuditavel;
        if (auditableObject != null)
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            state[Array.IndexOf(propertyNames, "CriadoEm")] = currentDate;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

A provider to retrieve the logged in user:

public class UsuarioProvider : Provider
{
    private Usuario _usuario;

```
protected override Usuario CreateInstance(IContext context)
{
    var usuariosRepositorio = context.Kernel.Get<IUsuariosRepositorio>(); // Stackoverflow on this line!!

    if (_usuario == null && WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
        _usuario = usuariosRepositorio.Get(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    return _usuario;
}
```

}

And the class `NinjectWebCommon` (web application) define:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IUsuario>().ToProvider<UsuarioProvider>().InRequestScope(); //.When((req) => WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    kernel.Load(new RepositoriosModule(), new MvcSiteMapProviderModule());
}
```

### [Add] Repository class

```
public class UsuariosRepositorio : Repositorio<Usuario>, IUsuariosRepositorio
{
    public UsuariosRepositorio(NHUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    { }
}


public class Repositorio<T> :  IRepositorio<T>
    where T : class, IEntidade
{

    private readonly NHUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get { return _unitOfWork; } }
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public Repositorio(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = (NHUnitOfWork)unitOfWork;
        _session = _unitOfWork.Context.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    }

    public void Remover(T obj)
    {
        _session.Delete(obj);
    }

    public void Armazenar(T obj)
    {
        _session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        return _session.Query<T>();
    }

    public object Get(Type entity, int id)
    {
        return _session.Get(entity, id);
    }

    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Query(expression).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return _session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return All().Where(expression);
    }
}
```

### Problem

The problem occurs in the class `UsuarioProvider` while trying to retrieve the user repository.

Stackoverflow error:

> `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll`

Comment: could you post code for class `UsuariosRepositorio` ?

Comment: Hi @jbl I edited the question .. look

Comment: Debugging should lead to the issue straight forward. Your mostl likely having a circular dependency, and if take a look at the stack trace and the arguments you will what causes the circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems :

The main problem I see is that `SessionFactoryBuilder` needs an `AuditInterceptor` which needs an `IUsuario`, which needs  a `UsuarioProvider`, which needs a `SessionFactoryBuilder`, thus introducing a cycle, and a stack-overflow.

The second problem I see is that your `AuditInterceptor` is linked to a request when your `SessionFactoryBuilder` is singleton like. I must confess I can't see how it work with several logged users.

You should instantiate and attach the `AuditInterceptor` as part of the `CreateSession`, instead of trying to create it once and for all as part of the Session builder. Once this is done, your interceptor should not rely on a Session that needs an AuditInterceptor as part of its creation (you may need a separate Session creation mechanism for that. A stateless Session might do the trick)

Comment: @Ridermansb BTW you don't seem to be using your `IUsuario usuarioLogado` in your AuditInterceptor, what do you need it for ? Also, you might just need the user id, which `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` already provides without needing to query database

Comment: `IUsuarioLogado'` I'll use later to set the properties (who created / modified the record), this is just a demo

Comment: About UserId agree. But not even figure out how to put these fields since I use ORM NHibernate and I also need the property in other situations. So the idea would be to have `CreateBy` (object) and `CreateById`

Comment: How can I configure IAuditInterceptor per session?

Comment: @Ridermansb the interceptor just needs to be instantiated and passed as parameter to the OpenSession method